# stroke issue in stackbar chart on aggregated bar

Tags: vega-lite, vega, vega-embed, vega-lite-api

I want to create horizontal stack bar chart with stroke line boundary  box on each aggregated sum  so that i can get the start and end point  separation of each sum aggregate in bar .
how can i do this in vegalite??

[Editor link](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUAwBOgtCrVICTJLrgBPKTPkBfJcm0BrfSe2KQcWVDbKassmigAB6BIEhkZNp8mHD6EAwI7gBmNHCCyvrmqekgdiDmoSlpGejEpqmYBXnegmxumiBFOegQIrk2NkA)

Comment: issue resolve by using stroke property of mark

Comment: Hi Shivam. please post your solution as an answer so the community can see how it worked and so the case gets closed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[Solution of stroke line on horizontal bar chart](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUAwBOgtCrVICTJLrgBPKTPkBfJcm0BrNKEzmccfSe2KQETNpsjp7oTIJIUM52IHCyUGzKNLJkLiAAHqlIZGTafJghfgwIvgBmNHCCyvrm5ZUg0eapZRVV6MSm5W71SvGCbD6aIM116BAi9TY2QA)

i just find stroke property under mark section that work for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).